# How to translate the triviality of computable Pareto optimality?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, computability-theory, markov-chains

I asked this question on [regular Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2481401/is-pareto-optimality-trivial-in-computable-environments), and got the "Tumbleweed" badge for it (basically, it was ignored). I hope to get a better (any) response here.

I recently stumbled upon [a paper relating to AI](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v40/Leike15.pdf). There I found a result that at first glance seems bewildering (p. 10):

**Theorem 18 (Pareto Optimality is Trivial)**. Every policy is Pareto optimal in any $\mathcal M\supseteq \mathcal M^{CSS}_{LSC}$.

A policy is a function $\pi:(\mathcal A\times\mathcal E)^*\rightarrow\mathcal A$ mapping each history to the action $a_t\in\mathcal A$ taken by the agent in time $t$ after seeing this history. An action results in the agent receiving a percept $e_t=(o_t,r_t)\in\mathcal E$ consisting of an observation $o_t\in\mathcal O$ and a real-valued reward $r_t\in\mathbb R$. A set $\chi^*:=\cup^{\infty}_{n=0}\chi^n$ is the set of all finite strings over the alphabet $\chi$. A history is an element of $(\mathcal A\times\mathcal E)^*$.

The $\mathcal M^{CSS}_{LSC}$ denotes the class of all environments modeled as lower semicomputable chronological conditional semimeasures. That is, mostly the class of [Markov decision processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_decision_process) satisfying those conditions. Pareto optimality is defined on p. 9 of the paper.

This theorem means i.a. that Pareto optimality is trivial in the class of all computable environments. Does this have a translation into a more general mathematical setting? For example, can we relate this to game theory and strategies taken by players in computable games? Does this mean that, in order to give a meaningful content to Pareto optimality, we must confine ourselves to uncomputable probabilities?

Comment: Maybe it's nontrivial when $\mathcal M\subset \mathcal M^{CSS}_{LSC}$

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen That would really restrict the available environments... In any case, my main question relates to the translatability of this theorem into more general mathematics.